# How do I use an INSERT INTO with this PL/SQL code block?

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, sql-insert, sql-like

I'm fairly new to the procedural language side of PL/SQL, so forgive me if this is basic.

I'm trying to put values in a table I've previously created outside of this code block. This code is currently getting an error on the sixth line. Any idea why?

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT name FROM clients) LOOP
    FOR d IN (SELECT customer_id, alt_name FROM customers) LOOP 
      IF d.alt_name LIKE '%' || c.name || '%'
      THEN
            INSERT INTO previously_made_table(name, customer_id, alt_name, customer_code) VALUES(c.name, d.customer_id, d.alt_name, '101');
            COMMIT;
       END IF;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Please post the error.  Thanks.

Comment: The error is PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CUSTOMER_CODE": invalid identifier

Comment: I should assure you that the table definitely has this field on it.

Comment: Can you try to run just the INSERT statement from SQLPlus (or you favourite Oracle tool)? Maybe you got the column name wrong...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked.

```
INSERT INTO previously_made_table VALUES(c.name, d.customer_id, d.alt_name, '101');
```

I cut the column names. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please, [always use a column list](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/2011/09/27/a-list-of-sql-best-practices/) in your INSERT INTO statements.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need pl\sql here

```
insert into previously_made_table
  (name, customer_id, alt_name, customer_code) 
 select c.name, d.customer_id, d.alt_name, '101'
 from   clients c , customers d
 where  d.alt_name LIKE '%' || c.name || '%'
```

Comment: True, but I'd prefer to know how to do it in the PL/SQL format I delivered the question in.

Comment: you probably don't have a column named `customer_code` in `previously_made_table`.

Comment: It's there, as mentioned in my comment above.